# Adjustment layer/filter to uniformly colorize illustrator objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create an image that contains a set of logos. Each logo has different colors and I need to neutralize them. I tried converting the image colors to gray scale but it's not uniform, some grays and darker than others. The end results should be something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this in Illustrator, preferably as a filter that I can toggle on/off?

Comment: why cannot you select all the objects and set any color you want to all of them?

Comment: @Ilan some logos are rather complex groupings of paths and setting a color doesn't maintain their design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*All this logos have the same fill color (C:45, M:30, Y:25, K:0).*

**So, to convert the logos to grayscale:**

- Select all the shapes.
- Edit > Edit colors > Recolor Artwork

[image]

- Change the numbers of colors displayed to 1

[image]

- Change the colorization method to exact.

[image]

- Double-click the color box > Select this color (C:45, M:30, Y:25, K:0) > Click OK.

**Example (two at the same time):**

[image]